# Expo / Auth0: Can't get PKCE Flow to work - Failed to verify code verifier

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, auth0, pkce

I'm using Expo + Auth0, following [the PKCE flow here](https://auth0.com/docs/authorization/flows/authorization-code-flow-with-proof-key-for-code-exchange-pkce). However, I am struggling to get it to work.

I receive an authorization code, but when I try to exchange the authorization `code` and `verifier` for an access token via a `POST` to `https://auth0-api-url.com/oauth/token`, it says `Failed to verify code verifier`.

Maybe how I'm creating the initial request is incorrect? This is what I am using to create a `challenge` and `verifier`.

```
import crypto from "crypto" // Node crypto package
const base64URLEncode = (str) => {
  return str.toString('base64')
    .replace(/\+/g, '-')
    .replace(/\//g, '-')
    .replace(/=/g, '')
}

const sha256 = (buffer) => {
  return crypto.createHash('sha256').update(buffer).digest();
}

export const createVerifier = () => {
  return base64URLEncode(crypto.randomBytes(32));
}

export const createChallenge = (verifier) => {
  return base64URLEncode(sha256(verifier))
}

export const generateState = () => {
  return Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15)
}

const verifier = createVerifier()
const challenge = createChallenge(verifier)
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you?
I had the same problem, but i found this article that give me the solution:
https://chrisfrewin.medium.com/auth0-expo-and-react-native-authorization-code-grant-flow-with-pkce-d612d098f5f3

Basically, theres a problem in how we generate the code_verifier. To solve this, you have to install the Buffer dependency.

```
yarn add buffer
```

And then, the code:

```
import * as Crypto from 'expo-crypto';
import * as Random from 'expo-random';
import { Buffer } from 'buffer';

function URLEncode(str): string {
    return str
        .replace(/\+/g, '-')
        .replace(/\//g, '_')
        .replace(/=/g, '');
}

async function sha256(buffer): Promise<string> {
    return await Crypto.digestStringAsync(
        Crypto.CryptoDigestAlgorithm.SHA256,
        buffer,
        { encoding: Crypto.CryptoEncoding.BASE64 }
    );
}

function generateShortUUID(): string {
    return Math.random()
          .toString(36)
          .substring(2, 15);
    }

 export async function generateChallange(){
     const state = generateShortUUID();
     const randomBytes = await Random.getRandomBytesAsync(32);
     const base64String = Buffer.from(randomBytes).toString('base64');
     const codeVerifier = URLEncode(base64String);
     const codeChallenge = URLEncode(await sha256(code_verifier));

     return { codeVerifier, codeChallenge, state}
    }
```

Hope this helps